# Cosmos DB Gremlin Query timeout

Tags: timeout, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, shortest-path

I am currently creating a PoC using Cosmos DB Graph. The data itself is around 100k nodes and 630k edges.
In one subset of this data (1.7k nodes and 3.8k edges) I am trying to find the shortest path from A to B with the gremlin.

Somehow this is not possible.
I get a query timeout (30 seconds) or I get a loop error (cannot exceed 32 loops) !?!?
There must be something wrong (on my side or Cosmos side) - can you please help or give a hint?
I tried a lot of query variants already, but the errors are still there...
[One of the basic queries I tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvtbn.png)

Answer (score 0):

The limits of the Gremlin API service are documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/gremlin-limits

It may be necessary that you are looking for an OLAP engine to process such a large shortest path query. You could consider Spark and their GraphFrame support to process it. Here is a sample: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-spark/blob/2.4/samples/graphframes/main.scala